# 301 Redirect for all broken links

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to redirect all broken links to the home page?

I have used the following but it gives me a redirect loop.

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.domain.com/
```

Also the following doesn't work for a wordpress site.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need a `page` for 404 error, not a directory(afaik)

Comment: If you are using Wordpress try this plugin -- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/  or else create an htaccess file

Comment: @Chasing Death
I'm trying to link it to the homepage. In this case, do I need a page to do the redirection?

WordPress has it own 404 error template page which I don't want.

Comment: Just use `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`, create a file called `404.php`, and that contains `<?php header('Location: /'); ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following on every single broken link on my wordpress site to solve the issue.

`ErrorDocument 404` doesn't work on **WordPress** site.

```
Redirect 301 /tags/something http://yoursite.com/
```